# Calling the value of dropdown, typescript

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm currently using Ionic Typescript. The problem that I'm encountering is I don't know how to call the values of my dropdown(i'm used to C# & java).

The algorithm is computing for IBW which only adds up if it exceeds 5ft.
Codes are:

`import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { NavController, Select } from "ionic-angular";


@Component({
  selector: "page-home",
  templateUrl: "home.html",
})

export class HomePage {
  /*let R : number = 52;
  let M : number = 56.2;
  let D : number = 50;
  let H : number = 48;*/
  M: number;
  R: number;
  D: number;
  H: number;
  *inches: number;
  ft: number;
  message: string;
  sex: string = 'f' && 'm';
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {}
  compute() {
    if(this.sex = 'm'){
      this.M = 56.2 + (1.41 * this.inches);
      this.R = 52 + (1.9 * this.inches);
      this.D = 50 + (2.3 * this.inches);
      this.H = 48 + (2.7 * this.inches);
    }
    else{
      this.M = 53.1 + (1.36 * this.inches);
      this.R = 49 + (1.9 * this.inches);
      this.D = 45.5 + (2.3 * this.inches);
      this.H = 45.5 + (2.2 * this.inches*);
    }
 }
}
**HOME.HTML:**

<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>IBW Calculator</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <h2>Ideal Weight Calculator</h2>
  Height in:
  <br /><br />
  <input type="number" name="ft" [(ngModel)]="ft"> feet
  <input type="number" name="inches" [(ngModel)]="inches"> inches <br /><br />
  <select id="sex" (change)="selectChangeHandler($event)">
    <option value="m">Male</option>
    <option value="f">Female</option>
  </select>
  <br /><br />
  <button ion-button color="primary" (click)="compute()">Compute</button>
  <p>Ideal weight according to:</p>
  Miller (1983) = {{M}}kg.
  <br /> Robinson (1983) = {{R}}kg.
  <br /> Devine (1983) = {{D}}kg.
  <br /> Hamwi (1983) = {{H}}kg.
</ion-content>`

Comment: you reference selectChangeHandler in your html but I do not see it in your component. Also I don't see reference to ngModel in your code. Personally I would do this with reactive forms rather than template-driven forms.

Comment: oh i was supposed to remove that because I just saw it around yt tutorials, but when I tried to put it in a component it encounters some errors.